# angularjs determine ng-click and href in my event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
md-list
  md-list-item.md-2-line ng-repeat="document in ctrl.documents"
    div.md-list-item-text ng-click="ctrl.getDocument($event, document)"
      span ng-bind-html="(document.content | trustedHtml)"
```

hi have this problem in my md-list i had `ng-click` naming `getDocument` this will do appear a dialog box which containe document. but in my `span` had content. contain html tag like `href`. example

`<span> blah blah blah blah </span><a href="person/1" target=_blanl >`

now the problem is when i click the link it will go the new tab and it will open dialog box

how can i determine if the user click the `href` or `the md-list`item so dialog will appear

```
@getDocument = (ev, document) =>
  console.log ev
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, the link is rendered inside your span, but when you click it, it sends you to another tab and still opens the dialog.

Your link is still [propagating](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) its click event to parent objects, so what you should do is either move the click event to another tag that doesn't contains links inside of it or add a "event.stopPropagation" to your link:

```
<a href="https://someurl" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">link</a>
```

Either of this shall work.

**EDIT:** for better design and avoid such problems as uninttended event propagation, maybe you could just do something like this:

```
md-list
  md-list-item.md-2-line ng-repeat="document in ctrl.documents"
    div.md-list-item-text
      button ng-click="ctrl.getDocument($event, document)"
      span ng-bind-html="(document.content | trustedHtml)"
```

Alternatively, you can also check for which element fired the click event. For example, since your main problem is with links, you can do something like this inside your getDocument() function:

```
ctrl.getDocument = function (event, document) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
    return;
  }

  // your code
}
```

Comment: i want to remain my ng-click is there chance to determine them in click event???

Comment: You can keep it there, but the link that is being generated kinda will need to have an stopPropagation. What you can do, too, if I'm not mistaken, is that you can check which object triggered the event, so you can just check for it on your getDocument function. I'd personally not recommend it, since it can become a mess, but it will work. I'll increment that on my answer.

Comment: i check event.target but i dont see tagName

Comment: im getting a span not an 'A'

Comment: i dont know but this work for me can you check this for me?  if event.target.attributeStyleMap.size !=2